# High CPU usage caused during select query

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

On running a select query with a QPS of 300+, query latency increases up to 20k ms with a CPU usage of ~100%. I couldn't identify what the issue could be over here!?

System details:

```
vCPUs: 16
RAM: 64 GiB
```

Create hypertable:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL, val1 TEXT NOT NULL, val2 DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL, val3 DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL);
SELECT create_hypertable('test_table', 'time');
SELECT add_retention_policy('test_table', INTERVAL '2 day');
```

Query:

```
SELECT * from test_table where val1='abc'
```

Timescale version:

```
2.5.1
```

No. of rows in test-table:

```
6.9M
```

Latencies:

```
 p50=8493.722203,
 p75=8566.074792,
 p95=21459.204448,
 p98=21459.204448,
 p99=21459.204448,
 p999=21459.204448
```

CPU usage of postgres SELECT query as per the htop command.

[image]

Comment: what type of disk are you using ? please post the iowait, io queue depth during the stress test

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Is there an index on val1 ? And what does EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) show you?

Comment: @mshabou Storage type is : Premium SSD LRS